# Dash on different line as commenter's username

Tags: bug, comments, design, grammar

In the comments section, I have noticed that often if the user's username gets carried over to the next line if it is too long. That is fine, but I have noticed that when this happens, the dash that precedes the username does not get carried over, like in this image. (This is just a random post I found on the Stack Overflow home page.)
[image]
You can see user Bram Vanroy's username in his comment is carried over to the next line but the dash isn't so you see:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut... –
`username`
As seen here:
[image]

If you can't see the images, I hope it should still be clear.

Comment: funny enough there is an `&nbsp;` after the `-`. Not sure why that isn't honored.

Comment: Could this be browser specific?  It shows up as expected (hyphen on the same line as the user name) for me in Firefox 67.0.2.

Comment: That's not a hyphen; it's a dash.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of chrome on MacOS

Comment: The source is ``&ndash;&nbsp;<a href="/users/…``.  I doubt it was the author's intent, but the only effect of this "nbsp" is to cause a space to appear at the beginning of the next line if it happens to wrap after the dash.  To work properly (i.e. as the OP expects), the equivalent of ``<span style="white-space:nowrap">&ndash;<a href="/users/… </a></span>`` would be needed.